# SQL - SAP HANA - REPLACE_REGEXPR in Column table

Tags: sql, hana, regexp-replace

I have some tables on SAP HANA and "create column table" to combine multiple "raw tables" and need to replace strings from one column in the newly created table. Tablename "Testsubject_status" Column name "STATUS".

The reason why I need to replace the strings, is to get a harmonized wording on specific entries.

With the following example, it is hopefully more clear what I mean:

Table name: Testsubject_status --- Column: Status

- Test me
- Test him
- Test with the ID 1237 is done
- Test her
- Test with the ID 928162 is done
- Test with the ID 991 is done

The result should be

Table name: Testsubject_status --- Column: Status

- Test me
- Test him
- Test is done
- Test her
- Test is done
- Test is done

I tried the following:

```
CREATE COLUMN TABLE SCHEMATTT.Testsubject_status AS (
    Select
        Table1.Person AS "Person",
        Table1.Vers AS "Vers",
        Table2.Flnr AS "Flnr",
        Table3.Status AS "Status"
    FROM 
        SCHEMATTT.Table1, SCHEMATTT.Table2, SCHEMATTT.Table3 
    WHERE SCHEMATTT.Table1.Person = SCHEMATTT.Table2.Person
    AND SCHEMATTT.Table2.Flnr = SCHEMATTT.Table3.Flnr

SELECT
    REPLACE_REGEXPR ('with the id \d{1,}' IN 'TEST with %' WITH '') "replace_regexpr"
    FROM SCHEMATTT.Testsubject_status
    );
```

Creating the table is working. The `Replace_Regexpr` statement is only working if I do not run it together with the create column table statement and then only creates a table with one column and the entries `TEST with %` in every row.

Additional info:

- There is not only the "Test is done" string that needs to be harmonized, but a few others as well. So I need to use the replace statement more than once in this specific column "Status"
- The `Test is done` Statement is not 1:1 with another Statement in the table, so the other statements can't be used in any way to do this :-)

Not sure if creating the table in this way is the best one, but I guess that's another story.

Thank you in advance for your input!

This Picture is for clarification in the comments:
[image: Status Entries and desired modification]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Mike, could you please try following SQLScript command

```
CREATE COLUMN TABLE Testsubject_status2 AS (
Select
    Table1.Person AS "Person",
    Table1.Vers AS "Vers",
    Table2.Flnr AS "Flnr",
    Table3.Status AS "Status",
    REPLACE_REGEXPR ('test with the id [[:digit:]]* is done' FLAG 'i' IN Table3.STATUS WITH 'Test is done') "replace_regexpr"
FROM 
   Table1, Table2, Table3 
WHERE Table1.Person = Table2.Person
AND Table2.Flnr = Table3.Flnr
);
```

This will produce a table with following sample data

[image]

Note that the STATUS column is replaced with a static text if there is a match for the given condition. Else the STATUS text is kept as it is

For the additional info, I added following expressions but I did not like it much
Maybe there are better solutions

```
REPLACE_REGEXPR (
    '(test with the id|Deployment for the ID) [[:digit:]]* is (done|completed)' 
    FLAG 'i' 
    IN Table3.STATUS 
    WITH 
        case 
            when Table3.STATUS LIKE_REGEXPR('test') Flag 'i' then 'test is done' 
            when Table3.STATUS LIKE_REGEXPR('deploy') Flag 'i' then 'deployment is done' 
            else Table3.STATUS
        end 
)  as "replace_regexpr_ext"
```

You can add this add a new calculated column in your table definitions script

I assume you have following status text in your table data:

- Deployment for the ID 234 is completed
- Deploy development

Comment: Thank you very much Eralper, really! The Statement is finally working! As stated in the "additional Info" part of my post, I would need to replace other Strings like the "Test is done“ as well. If I put the REPLACE_REGEXPR Statement in a CASE WHEN Table3.Status like ‘test with the ID % is done’ then REPLACE_REGEXPR ('test with the id [[:digit:]]* is done' FLAG 'i' IN Table3.STATUS WITH 'Test is done') "replace_regexpr" ELSE WHEN xxxxx ELSE WHEN xxx ELSE Table3.STATUS end as replace_regexpr FROM Table3 I get a Syntax is incorrect near """ error message. Do you know what the Problem could be?

Comment: I added a new expressions that you can use as a seperate column data in your code, I hope it helps

Comment: Again, thank you very much Eralper, Maybe I was not clear enough with my wording About the different Status entries. The do not only have this pattern like you assumed. Just to Name a few: Test [[with the ID 1237]] is done, Ticketnumber[[: 9G62J]], [[OE_1559C: ]]New RSKT.... in these examples the part that needs to be removed is marked in [[]] …. sorry for the missunderstanding and thanks again for your patients and help! Edit: I have about 20 different wordings that need to be harmonized

Comment: And as a result what do you want to see in the output? You can use " | " pipe sign to search for static text in status, but if you want to modify the output then maybe we should use place holders

Comment: Test [[with the ID 1237]] is done should be Test is done - Ticketnumber:9G62J should be Ticketnumber - OE_1559C: New RSKT should be New RSKT

Comment: i guess that is wrong: '(test with the id % is done  |Ticketnumber %| OE_% New RSKT) [[:digit:]]* is (done|''|New RSKT)' ….especially single quotes in single qoutes are not working?!

Comment: I added a table to my post above… that should give you a more clear Picture of what data looks like... as mentioned before… there are several entries that need to be harmonized despite the once I posted (total of about 20)